# Migrate import with authentication onto external site

Tags: 8, migrations

What configuration is needed in to use the MigratePlus authentication plugin. I need to authenticate the migrate import requests so that I can successfully import files behind a login.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more detail? What sort of authentication do you need? The migrate_plus module has three authentication plugins - basic, digest, and oauth2. The first two take 'username' and 'password' in their configuration - oauth2, naturally, is quite a bit more complex.